# dkpg not found error code 1

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, updates

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dirmngr gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gnupg2 gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv
  openssl
13 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
13 standard security updates
Need to get 0 B/3,435 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/00-gpg-wks-client_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/00-gpg-wks-client_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/01-dirmngr_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/01-dirmngr_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/02-gnupg-utils_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/02-gnupg-utils_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/03-gpg-wks-server_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/03-gpg-wks-server_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/04-gpg-agent_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/04-gpg-agent_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/05-gpg_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/05-gpg_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/06-gpgconf_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/06-gpgconf_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/07-gnupg-l10n_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_all.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/07-gnupg-l10n_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/08-gnupg_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_all.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/08-gnupg_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/09-gpgsm_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/09-gpgsm_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/10-gpgv_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/10-gpgv_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/00-gpg-wks-client_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/01-dirmngr_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/02-gnupg-utils_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/03-gpg-wks-server_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/04-gpg-agent_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/05-gpg_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/06-gpgconf_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/07-gnupg-l10n_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/08-gnupg_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/09-gpgsm_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-8sELeG/10-gpgv_2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know much. I am new to Linux and don't know where to start.

Comment: This isn't a question: it's a paste from your terminal. Please read [How to Ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions without sufficient context and details are unlikely to be answered. Include enough details that we know what you're asking and context so we know what you've already done. We also ask that you search and research before asking. Proofread before submitting and write to the best of your ability. Many people will not want to help if it seems you've put no effort into asking. For a more thorough explanation of how to ask effectively, see: http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Please provide OS & release details; you mention only Linux - but this isn't SE *Unix & Linux*, it's SE *Ask Ubuntu*.

Comment: ubuntu 22.04 and the kde plasma x11 desk top enviorment

Comment: evreytime i try to do sudo upgrade it comes back with dpkg error i just read up on the snap store also being alot of issues with the version i have so i purged all the systems out i had kali repositorys i missed that are now removed where i added the toolset so that fixed most issues i had but the one thing it keeeps coming back is error code one dpkg etc... cannot be found and i do apolgise i was getting to the point of throwing the thing when i finlly come here to submit the q?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually repack the .deb:

```
first you need to know where apt stores packages (example: /var/cache/apt/archives/ )

save the following code as shell script (example: repack.sh)


#!/bin/bash
ar x $1
zstd -d < control.tar.zst | xz > control.tar.xz
zstd -d < data.tar.zst | xz > data.tar.xz
ar -m -c -a sdsd ~/package.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz
rm debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz control.tar.zst data.tar.zst
dpkg -i ~/package.deb
```

and execute :

```
repack.sh /var/cache/apt/archives/zst-compressed-package.deb
```

Comment: Brilliant! 
It worked flawlessly!